# AWS Lambda: Get current retry attempt count at runtime

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda

I have an AWS Lambda (`python3.7` runtime) that runs certain task, and its `MaximumRetryAttempts` is set to `1` (meaning it can fail once, then have 1 more try).

For a reasons I won't get into, I want to know, at runtime, if this is the first attempt or the second. Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score -1):

```
import json
import boto3
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time

aws_cloud_watch_logs_client = boto3.client('logs')
lambda_invocation_count_query = "fields @retry_count | filter @message like 'REPORT' AND @requestId = '{lambda_request_id}' | stats count(@message) as retry_count"
aws_cloud_watch_log_group = '/aws/lambda/mylambdaname' # Set aws cloudwatch log group name as per your setup

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    lambda_retry_counts=get_lambda_retry_count(context)
    print("lambda_retry_counts=",lambda_retry_counts)
    #TODO : your logic here
    

# refactor to reduce complexity, might extract method to cover single responsibility principle
def get_lambda_retry_count(context):
    print("context.aws_request_id=", context.aws_request_id)
    qry=lambda_invocation_count_query.format(lambda_request_id=context.aws_request_id)
    print(qry)
    start_query_response = aws_cloud_watch_logs_client.start_query(
    logGroupName=aws_cloud_watch_log_group,
    startTime=int((datetime.today() - timedelta(hours=1)).timestamp()), # Refactor as per your requirement
    endTime=int(datetime.now().timestamp()),
    queryString=qry,
    )

    query_id = start_query_response['queryId']

    response = None

    while response == None or response['status'] == 'Running':
        print('Waiting for cloud watch query to complete ...')
        time.sleep(10) # Refactor as per your requirement
        response = aws_cloud_watch_logs_client.get_query_results(
            queryId=query_id
        )
    
    if response['results']:
        return response['results'][0][0]['value'] # refactor for readability, maintenance
    else:
        return 0
```

Alternative, To query aws cloud watch, you can also use AWS System Parameter Store with aws_request_id as part of Parameter name to uniquely identify it. Furthermore, keep lambda retry count as value of this Parameter. Increment it per execution of lambda based on aws_request_id. If threshold reach then handle as per your logic and delete the AWS System Parameter Store with name having the aws_request_id for which threshold is reached. Summary- you just need some storage which keeps mapping of aws_request_id and retry count.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the plug-and-play solution. In my case, I think polling is less relevant, but using AWS System Parameter Store might be it.
I was looking for something more simple, but it looks like there isn't any other alternative.

Comment: The solution as proposed above shouldn't work in all cases. This is because both cloudwatch logs and cloudwatch logs insights are asynchronous to the request. If the retry happens before cloudwatch logs insights receives the log entries and updates its indexes, the query will return a number smaller than reality.