# Get Cloud Watch logs from differnet lambda functions or applications

Tags: java, python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to fetch Cloud watch logs for different lambda fucntions and trace for a pertucular string just like insights becasue we have some set of lambda functions and applications which need to run for a perticular job. Many time some of the services stop runnig due to some issues so i want to trace them with perticulart string and get error report where it got errored.

Eg : Lambda1 will call Lambda2 and Lambda2 will add entry in DynamoDB.
Now i want to create a lambda function which will trace lambda 1 and lambda 2 give me report if both lambdas run succesfully for a perticular JOBID.

So far i have tryed to use AWS Cloud watch as a trigger but it is giving log only for 1 perticular function but not for all functions.

Comment: [Lambda/Boto3 code to check AWS Cloud Watch logs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65760571/14843902) and Example of [AWS Cloud Watch insight query to filter out specific logs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65955295/14843902) of use to you?

Comment: I tried using Boto3 but i am getting access denied exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Python library called Boto3 which helped me to resolve this issue.The Lambda function should have a peoper read access to fetch the logs or the corrosponding lambda fucntions we are tracking.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).